# In jQuery, how do I select elements between elements with certain classes?

Tags: jquery

I have an unordered list.

```
<ul>
    <li class="foo">Baz</li>
    <li>Select Me!</li>
    <li>Select Me!</li>
    <li>Select Me!</li>
    <li class="bar">Baz</li>
    <li>Don't Select Me</li>
    <li>Red Herring List Item</li>
</ul>
```

How do I select the list items in between the list items with classes foo and bar using jQuery? I do not know the contents of any list items. I also do not know how many list items are there to be selected so I cannot depend on a count.

Comment: [`$('li.bar').prevUntil('li.foo')`](http://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/)

Comment: Checkout the source code in my answer if it's interesting you...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
$('li.foo').nextUntil('li.bar')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zZRDB/1/

Comment: i had absolutely no idea this existed

Comment: Thank you! fyi, you could use `$('li.foo').nextUntil('li.bar').css('background', '#f00');` instead of using the "attr" method. :D

Answer (score 12):

```
var $elements = $('.bar').prevUntil('.foo');
```

Or the other way:

```
var $elements = $('.foo').nextUntil('.bar');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/LMZ7Z/1)

---

If you're intersted to know how it's implemented, [check out the source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js):

```
nextUntil: function(elem, i, until) {
    return jQuery.dir(elem, "nextSibling", until);
},
prevUntil: function(elem, i, until) {
    return jQuery.dir(elem, "previousSibling", until);
},​

dir: function(elem, dir, until) {
    var matched = [],
        cur = elem[dir];

    while (cur && cur.nodeType !== 9 && (until === undefined || cur.nodeType !== 1 || !jQuery(cur).is(until))) {
        if (cur.nodeType === 1) {
            matched.push(cur);
        }
        cur = cur[dir];
    }
    return matched;
},​
```

Comment: @VisioN. I thought for the DEMO, it's nice, color changing... **2012**

Comment: Where is color animation? I've seen better :P

Comment: That's neat. That just taught me how to do animations in javascript. Thanks :D Very useful red herring.

Comment: @gdoron In the demo, It's highlighting the content between classes only, how to include that classes content also.

Comment: @nani0077 you can simply go with `index` and a `for` loop back and forth.

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
 $('li.bar').prevUntil('.foo')
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/2W883/1/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var index1 = $('li.foo').index(),
    index2 = $('li.bar').index()-1;

    $('li:gt('+ index1+'):lt('+ index2+')', 'ul');
```

or `$('li.foo').nextUntil('li.bar');`

or `$('li.bar').prevUntil('li.foo');`